# Regex deleting word and finding word

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find and delete the https part in a sentence.
I use `re.search("^https://t.co/.*[a-zA-Z]"`,data)`
and the result is :

```
match='https://xx.x/ekGSeJufuH 7 jalan indonesia yang pa

match='https://xx.x/okbymT3g'
```

But I want to just take `match='https://xx.x/ekGSeJufuH` and delete while keeping the rest of the word. I there something wrong with my regex ?

Comment: Please show a *complete* example. There should be enough of your code that someone else can run it without modification and see the problem. You should show explicitly what is the input, what is the output that you get, and what is the output you want instead.

Comment: Rather than using regex, you could have just found the first space and kept everything afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

.* matches any characters including whitespace.

An easier way is that

1. find a sentense starting with 'https://',
2. find the first whitespace(' ') in the sentence,
3. delete substring before the whitespace.

I think it works because the URL doesn't allow any WS inside.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you just want to exclude the `"https://"` from the string. If so, this may be a regular expression you're looking for:

```py
r"https://(.*)"
```

Using the above regular expression with the addresses you provided:

```py
>>> regex = re.compile(r"https://(.*)")
>>> regex.search("https://xx.x/ekGSeJufuH 7 jalan indonesia yang pa").group(1)
'xx.x/ekGSeJufuH 7 jalan indonesia yang pa'
>>> regex.search("https://xx.x/okbymT3g").group(1)
'xx.x/okbymT3g'
```

If there are more criteria for the regular expression which I missed, just comment on my answer and I'll update the regular expression accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to tweak it a little bit and solves it with

```
re.search("^https://t.co/\S*",txt)
```

Comment: If it works, it works, but I don't see how this regular expression would match the addresses provided in the question.